# What is the next objective?

Tags: discussion

Congratulations to all the people who have put so much time and hard work into making this site.

Great job and thank you!

Comment: The next objective? That's easy, to graduate the site. But what then? :-)

Comment: Then we become the most popular site in the network and take over the world :D